# How to fix number of labels does not match number of samples?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to run Random forest Classifier,after test_train_split,when I run it generates an error that number of samples doesnt match with sample.
I have 960 rows and 26 columns.

```
X=pd.read_csv('csv',delimiter=',',sep=",",quotechar='"',header=None,quoting=2,error_bad_lines=False,na_values="")
X=X.drop([0,2,4,5],axis=1)
X= X.fillna('')
X= X[0:961].astype("int")
features= X.columns
Y= X[27] #my labels
Y= Y[0:961].astype("int") # Converting datatype string to int
Y=Y[np.isfinite(X[27])] # Remove NAN values from my label Y
x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test=train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.3)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50,max_depth=3)
clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

Comment: What is `Y= X[27]#int(X.shape[1] - 2)`?? Also, pls edit your code to remove stuff irrelevant to the question (`features`, `tmp`). And you don't have any classifier here...

Comment: @desertnaut,please review again I have edited my code now

Comment: Where *exactly* does the error happen, and what *exactly* is it? If it happens at `train_test_split`, as you imply, all code below that line is irrelevant to the error and should be removed. Please post the full error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

The first is that, while you remove the NaN values from your label Y:

```
Y=Y[np.isfinite(X[27])] # Remove NAN values from my label Y
```

you don't do the same with your features X; hence, you end up with a different number of samples for your features X & labels Y, and `train_test_split` gives an expected error.

Since you have removed the NaN values from your Y, it makes no sense to keep the respective rows in your X; so, you should add

```
X=X[np.isfinite(X[27])] # remove rows with NaN labels
```

The second issue is that your `train_test_split` assignment is wrong (check the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)); it should be

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.3)
```

Comment: @deserthaunt thank you so much,it worked,but now clf.score() is giving me value "1.0" that means efficiency is 100%?? can it be happen? what will be the analysis?

Comment: @Anypitcher RF is a powerful classifier, and it's not unheard of it producing *training* accuracies of 100%, especially in relatively small datasets, such as yours; cannot offer any further opinion without knowing the data...